# Php/MySQL error when searching DB

Tags: php, mysql

I have an MySQL error and I cannot figure it out... It was working and now it is not working anymore (I haven't done anything to the database).

Here is the query:

`$querySearch = "SELECT * FROM cars WHERE (price >= {$startPrice} AND price <= $endPrice) AND condition = '{$condition}'";`

Here is the form:

```
<h3>Condition:</h3>
<span class="searchRange">
<select name="condition" class="condition">
    <option value="any">Any Condition</option>
    <option value="Brand New">Brand New</option>
    <option value="Near New">Near New</option>
    <option value="Good">Good</option>
    <option value="Ok">Ok</option>
    <option value="Poor">Poor</option>
</select>
</span>
```

And here is how PHP receives the data:

`$condition = mysql_prep($_POST['condition']);`

`mysql_prep()` is a user made function that just takes care of the magic quote stuff.

Anyone see where an error could occur?

> Error: Database query failed: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'condition = 'Near New'' at line 1

Comment: It would help if you told us *what* the error was...

Comment: you should really be using a prepared statement for this instead of doing your own escaping.

Comment: Could you tell us what error is given from PHP and MySQL? Have you tried writing the query directly into Workbench/PHPMyAdmin?

Comment: Database query failed: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'condition = 'Near New'' at line 1

Comment: possible duplicate of [Syntax error due to using a reserved word as a table or column name in MySQL](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23446377/syntax-error-due-to-using-a-reserved-word-as-a-table-or-column-name-in-mysql)

Comment: Ian... I posted this over a year ago. That question you linked was asked last month.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Condition is a [reserved keyword](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/reserved-words.html)

Enclose it in backticks.

```
AND `condition` =
```

Comment: Wow... Thank you a bunch, saved me a lot of heartache! Will accept when time is up. Thank you again.